# TSQL; Way to pivot results with aggregation

Tags: t-sql

I have that task trying to produce result for that sample code like on pic.
Test code I attached works but partially, I need just single line for West, South... and then have count in each bucket. Is this possible with TSQL 2012.
Tx
[*Sample of input output click here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4dWj.jpg)

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT  'WEST' Side, '2015-1-1' DD, 1 Status  UNION ALL
  SELECT  'WEST' Side, '2015-1-1' DD, 2 Status  UNION ALL
 SELECT  'WEST' Side, '2015-1-1' DD, 2 Status  UNION ALL
 SELECT  'WEST' Side, '2015-1-1' DD, 3 Status  UNION ALL
 SELECT  'WEST' Side, '2015-1-1' DD, 3 Status  UNION ALL
 SELECT  'WEST' Side, '2015-1-1' DD, 3 Status UNION ALL
  SELECT  'South' Side, '2015-1-1' DD, 3 Status   )
   --SELECT * FROM cte 

 SELECT side, 
   case when Status= 1 then sum(1) else sum(0) end Complete,
    case when Status= 2 then sum(1) else sum(0) end Cancel,
   case when Status= 3 then sum(1) else sum(0) end  Future 
  -- COUNT(*) TotalCC
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY Side, Status
 ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: After reviewing your image, if that is the outcome you are aiming for, I don't think you need a PIVOT operator here. What you did above (minus the DD column) would be the best solution I could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
    SELECT
        Side
        , 1 AS agg_col
        , StatusOfSide
    FROM
        <table_name>
)

SELECT
    Side
    , [1] AS Complete
    , [2] AS Cancel
    , [3] AS Future
FROM
    PivotData
    PIVOT (COUNT(agg_col) FOR StatusOfSide IN ([1], [2],[3]) ) p;
```